# iOS7:UISearchbar shifts up when I want it to stay in place

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have an App that is similar to this http://www.raywenderlich.com/16873/how-to-add-search-into-a-table-view tutorial. My App has a search bar, a tableview and a searchdisplaycontroller just like the example link. It all works fine except on iOS7 the search bar overlaps the navigationcontroller like so when I begin searching.[image]

How do I stop the search bar from shifting up? I looked at some other stack-overflow answers and it just has me going in circles.

Comment: Keep in mind that if you happen to find a way to keep it from shifting up, there will be almost no space left between your segmented control and the keyboard to show your search results.

Comment: I know, this isn't the app I need to apply it to, just an example app.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://blog.ittybittyapps.com/blog/2013/11/08/working-with-ios-6-and-7/ The solution is use "self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;"

Comment: Unfourntantly it doesn't work in my app or the App example

Answer (score 0):

Try adding below code snippet in your ViewController.

```
 if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```

Answer (score 0):

[`edgesForExtendedLayout`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/edgesForExtendedLayout) has nothing to do with this. this is simply standard behavior of `UISearchDisplayController` (since day one, afaicr).

what i usually do is not to use `UISearchDisplayController` at all but a plain `UISearchBar` as the table view's `tableHeaderView`. you'll then lose the gray background and `UISearchDisplayController`'s callbacks but you can still implement a proper search via [`UISearchBarDelegate` methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchBarDelegate_Protocol/index.html).

also, fwiw, `UISearchDisplayController` is [deprecated as of iOS 8](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchDisplayController_Class/).